# Cannot use Android classes in NativeScript 2

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I am using **NativeScript 2.0** with **Visual Studio Code** and **TypeScript 1.8** support (**Windows**).

I am developing a module, lets say **MyModule-common.ts** with an Android specific implementation (**MyModule.android.ts**).

**Currently I cannot access Android classes!**

If I write something like

```
var MyModule = require("./MyModule-common");

export class MyClass {
    private _activity: android.app.Activity;
}
```

I get

> error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'android'

when I build my project.

Is there something to install extra or configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TypeScript definition files for Android are by default not included as they are fairly large.

You can get then by doing a **npm install tns-platform-declarations --save-dev**

Comment: Good to know as I'd like to venture into NativeScript and TypeScript.

Comment: You don't need the extra type declarations for TypeScript; they are only really useful if you are planning on doing specific Native Android stuff.  The type declarations files are present for the whole framework by default.

Comment: using the definitions in `tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts` there's missing things? For instance, I can't access `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar` because 'android.support' has no exported member 'design' what am I missing?

Comment: made a question to clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079773/how-to-use-the-native-android-widgets-type-definitions-in-nativescript