# How to use the native android widgets type definitions in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, typescript, nativescript

I installed the platform definitions by adding `"tns-platform-declarations": "^2.5.2"`However, when I use the definitions in `tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts` I can't access certain parts of the API. For instance, I can't access `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`

```
  private snackbar: android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
```

because 'android.support' has no exported member 'design' what am I missing? When I go to code complete, I get only 'android.v4' and v4 does not contain a "design" module.

*I also tried* to import directly using the 'app' object as somebody suggested:

```
  import * as app from 'application';
  private snackbar = app.android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
  // error: 'application' has no member 'android'
```

With the above, I get code completion, but a red squiggly under `android` and tsc won't compile.

The only alternative I have found, is similar to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702610/nativescript-augment-tns-platform-declarations) which isn't really a solution, as I can cheat like this, too:

```
declare var android:any;
```

**How do I actually use the TS definitions to compile and get code completion?**

Comment: Kind of irrelevant but, I have toyed around with nativescipt a bit, and while it is a great project, I would wager to say that using it with all the functionality you want, is likely more of a headache than learning Java and Swift separately and using those.

Comment: For reference, here's an example of using the native Android API from TypeScript: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-snackbar/blob/master/snackbar.android.ts I'm basically trying to figure out why intellisense is broken for me in this case.

Comment: There's an experimental type definitions generating tool for the android sdk, and android support libraries used in the project. Do a build/run with the `--androidTypings` flag to have d.ts' generated for you. They should contain the classes that you can't find in the platform-declarations, as they are generated against the versions used in your project.

Comment: Oh great, thanks! trying it out today then, will update with results.

Comment: --androidTypings totally worked! make it an answer so I can give you your points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an experimental type definitions generating tool for the android sdk, and android support libraries used in the project. Do a build/run with the `--androidTypings` flag to have d.ts' generated for you.

Those should contain the classes that you can't find in the platform-declarations, as they are generated against the versions used in your project.

`tns build android --androidTypings`